# How do I fix multiple Google Talk Plugin "unsuccessful application installation" errors daily?

Tags: windows-7, google-talk

I was reminded by a recent [Lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5932456/7-awesome-features-youve-forgotten-about-in-windows-7) about the Reliability Monitor tool in Windows 7. This morning I opened Reliability Monitor and was greeted by this:

[image: my Reliability Monitor page, report dated 4 Aug 2012]

There are 5 warnings daily for the Google Talk Plugin. An example of the "technical details":

[image: screen from "view technical details", dated 5 Aug 2012]

> Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Google Talk Plugin. Product Version: 3.3.3.8675. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Google. Installation success or error status: 1603.

This problem has been going on all the way back to 12 November 2011, but I just noticed it in Reliability Monitor today.

The thing is, I can't uninstall the Google Talk plugin because it isn't even listed in Programs and Features!

[image: Programs and Features, sorted by publisher. dated 7 August 2012]

Any advice, Super Users? What's going on here? Is this normal behavior? If not, how do I fix it?

Comment: You should try to install Google Talk Plugin once more and this time download a new fresh setup may be the last one is corrupted. After installing it check out if it appear in the uninstall list of the programs.

Comment: downloaded a fresh new installer from [here](http://www.google.com/talk/) and it threw the following error: `The installer encountered error 1603: Fatal error during installation`

Comment: See this [Google product froum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/J93j4YdOUtA) and also try to run the setup with admin privileges.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me the issue likely started with a bad install of Chrome and a fix that required editing the registry (HKCU/Software/Google/Update/Clients and ../ClientState).

The solution (to the Gtalk Plugin error 1603() issue was to use the following tool (http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall/) to scan, choose "problems installing a program", then selecting "Google Talk Plugin" from the list it provided and when that was done, then to revisit http://www.google.com/talk/ and "Install video chat plug-in".

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood about your problem this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247515) might help. The resolution part gives proper steps to uninstall application not present in the **Programs and Features** but can be removed from the **Registry**.

**EDIT** : As mentioned in the above comments, if the re-installation does not work properly for you I have found that this is another possible solution:

1. Logging out of Gmail
2. Going to **C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Google\Google Talk Plugin** on Windows7
3. Delete the file **googletalkplugin_port**
4. Log back into Gmail, it should be working again.

Check if this works

Comment: doesn't show up in the registry either...

Comment: For 1603 error refer [microsoft forums](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834484)

Comment: does this solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 30 was recently (6/20/14) installed as an update. After that I got the error using Firefox and none of the solutions (short of going into the Registry) worked.

I then switched to Chrome and voila, it worked. Problem is with the new Firefox update,

Answer (score 0):

Check Windows Update for KB2918614 and uninstall if present
Uninstall and reinstall Chrome
Download and install GoogleVoiceAndVideoSetup (available from the phone dialer in Chat - NOT Hangouts)