# How to fix an "install loop" when installing Google Talk plugin on Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-talk

I'm trying to install the Google Talk plugin on a computer running Windows 7 64 bit, Chrome.

It appears I am stuck in an "install loop" - whenever I click "install the plugin", everything seems to progress correctly, I download an exe, the install finishes correctly ... and then I am back where I started, without a working Google Talk plugin.

Steps I've tried to resolve this:

1. I have manually removed all instances of Google Talk from my system.
2. I have tried to [install Microsoft's "Fix It tool"](https://superuser.com/a/487765/241).

Any other ideas? Should I uninstall and install Chrome? (A bit reluctant to try this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, uninstalling and installing Chrome was the answer for me :)